# Copy by value in CatlogSynchJob in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, catalog

What is **Copy by value** in CatalogSynchJob in Hybris. If I make **Copy by value** true for my Attribute. How is it working in CatalogSynchJob ??

Comment: Attribute value in the target item will be cleared.

For a reference, it will be null, for a collection it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If **partof** true in items.xml in relation,then only we can make **copyByValue** as true, we cannot make **copyByValue** as false.

If partof and copyByvalue is true,then pk of staged version attribute will be same as online version pk. Because we copy the staged version attribute value to online version attribute value.